# ══Exception caught by widgets library ═ Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget

Tags: flutter

I am getting this error

```
══Exception caught by widgets library ═ Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget
```

I used inside siglechild scrolview ListView.bulder. See all the code in the photo from beginning to end.

[image]

Comment: Please learn about formatting, https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting , then apply it towards more somber design. Please do no provide textual info as picture of text. Please try for [answer] and a [mre]. Please take the [tour].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.